# Magento get product availiblity on checkout review

Tags: checkout, qty-increment

I want to check the availiblity of a product and display that on the review block inside the checkout.

Therefore I want to edit the following file:

```
/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
```

I need something like this:

```
<?php $inventoryQuantity = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); ?>
<?php if($inventoryQuantity <= 0): ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I achieve that? Because that does not work. It always load value 0, when checking `<?php echo inventoryQuantity; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting  ***inventory  direct from id***,first need to fetch cart item sku then getinventory

```
$sku = $_item->getSku();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
//Get stock information of the loaded product
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I do not get any result when loading `<?php echo $stock?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php $_product = $_item->getProduct();?>
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span>
<?php else: ?>
       <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**OR**

```
$_product = $_item->getProduct();
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
$qty = $stock->getQty();
```

**OR**

```
$_product = $_item->getProduct();
$stock = $_product->getStockItem();
$qty = $stock->getQty();
```

Comment: Pls check now updated ans

Comment: Thanks, I tried both new options and these does also not work. `<?php echo $stock;?>` is not displaying any result.

Comment: It is prefect ans. I think your are missing some else :). What is magento vesion.?